# Can I restore a .bmp file of full database backup to an Oracle 12c EE instance running on RDS?

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-12c, recovery, remote

I've got an Oracle 12c EE database set up on an RDS box with no SSH access. I do, however, have SQL Developer and SQL PLUS tools.

Is there any way I can restore a full backup into this database using these tools (or any other remote management utility)?

Comment: what is a .bfull backup?

Comment: @AndrewBrennan see my reply to JSapkota below their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchanging several comments I came to know that you have Data Pump file of full database. Anyway you can use the SQL Developer to import export database objects. Just follow the steps:

1) Launch the SQL Developer and go to `View` menu and click on `DBA`.

[image]

2) Then add database connection to perform Data Pump operations.

[image]

3) Click on Data Pump and select the appropriate job wizard.
[image]

4) Right click on Data Pump and Data Pump import wizard.
[image]

[image]
Useful link:

[Using DBA Features in SQL Develope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/appdev.32/e35117/intro.htm#RPTUG45282)

Comment: This has been hugely helpful already, but I'm looking to restore a database from a .BFULL file which I already have on hand, rather than from a backup of the database I have access to via SQL Developer. (This is part of an extremely awkward migration, which is unfortunately mostly out of my control). As a side note, I'd upvote this if I had the local rep to do so.

Comment: @Jules: What is .BFULL file? Is that file a Data Pump file?  Sorry I couldn't find its meaning. I thought you have full RMAN backup. Its Oracle Backup type or else?

Comment: it's the extension of the file given to me by a client; I'm an extreme Oracle SQL novice, and the only documentation I found online pointed to this being a "full file backup" of an Oracle database. I hadn't heard of this extension before a few days ago myself.

Comment: The only docs I've found that even contain "bfull" on Oracle's website are for the `impdp` tool, for what it's worth.